# Is it posible to delete `div` from template?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router, vue-resource

I have a component `myHello`:

```
<temlate>
    <div>
       <h2>Hello</h1>
       <p>world</p>
    </div>
</template>
```

And main component:

```
<h1>my hello:</h1>
<my-hello><my-hello>
```

After rendering shows this:

```
<h1>my hello:</h1>
<div>
   <h2>Hello</h1>
   <p>world</p>
</div>
```

How to delete `<div>` ?

Comment: Why would you want to do that ? There are two ways by which you can do it but .. why?

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal it is just example what I want :) but it really need to realize, but I don't know how

Comment: So, what happens if you replace the `div` with `template`? I mean let the first `template` tag be there as is, replace the `div` you want to be deleted with ``template` as well.

Answer (score 2):

With VueJS, every component must have only one root element. The [upgrade guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Fragment-Instances-removed)  talks about this. If it makes you feel better, you are not [alone](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/any-way-to-get-rid-of-root-element-in-component-template/1620). For what it's worth the [components section](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) is a good read.

With the myriad of solutions to your problem, here is one.

component `myHello`:

```
<temlate>
  <h2>Hello</h1>
</template>
```

component `myWorld`:

```
<temlate>
  <p>world</p>
</template>
```

component `main`

```
<h1>my hello:</h1>
<my-hello><my-hello>
<my-world><my-world>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue gives you the tools to do so by creating templates or you can do it by having a parent div with two parent divs as children. Reset the data from the data function. Stick with convention (create templates). It's hard to get used to use Vue when you have a jQuery background. Vue is better

Ex.

```
data () {
 message: 'My message'
}
```

When you click a button to display a new message. Clear the message or just set the message variable with a new value.
ex. this.message = 'New Message'

If you like to show another div. you should used the if - else statement and add a reactive variable. Ex. showDivOne

```
data () {
   message: 'My message'
   showDivOne: true,
   showDivTwo: false
}
```

Add this reactive variables to the parent divs that corresponds to the div.
When clicking the button, you should have a function like...

```
methods: {
 buttonClick () {
  this.showDivOne = false
  this.showDivTwo = true
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `v-if` directive to controll. Add a flag to controll status to show or hide